# Rails: virtual attribute not working from custom class / seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I do not seem to be able to make a virtual attribute work in conjunction with a custom class / seeds.rb file. Here's the relevant code:

*picture.rb*

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :crop_width
  has_attached_file :image, styles: Proc.new { |clip| clip.instance.attachment_sizes }

  def attachment_sizes
    logger.info("crop_width: #{crop_width}")
    # some processing
  end
end
```

*pictures_controller.rb*

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    Picture.create(crop_width: 500, image: params[:image])
  end
end
```

*lib/website_components.rb*

```
module WebsiteComponents
  class Component
    def self.create_pictures
      Picture.create(
        crop_width: 500, 
        image: File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'image.png'), 'r')
      )
    end
  end
end
```

*seeds.rb*

```
require 'website_components'
WebsiteComponents::Component.create_pictures
```

For some reason, calling the create action from pictures_controller.rb results in `'crop_width: 500'` whereas running seeds.rb results in `'crop_width: '`. Any help is greatly appreciated on how to make this virtual attribute work from my custom class / seeds.rb

Comment: After modifying the lib/website_components.rb do you restart your console?   The lib files doesn't get autoloaded with the changes after save the file or reload! you current console if you haven't defined lib as an autoload path.

Comment: @JorgeNajeraT thanks for the information, didn't know that yet. That, however, doesn't fix my problem. I included some more relevant code, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I think you are running on some problems because of the Proc.new. As you are trying to make dynamic style with paperclip I would suggest you to check this wiki https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation and use a lamba instead. If you really need to make an extra processing of the image with ImageMagick you should check this screencast http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images Hope it helps.